# Duplicate sources.list entry in update after Tor install

Tags: debian, software-installation

trying to install Tor on Debian 8.11 following Tor project [instructions](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en), i get this warning when updating the system

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.debian.org_dists_jessie_updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

This is my /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib
deb http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main
deb https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org jessie main
deb-src https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org jessie main
```

How can i safely solve this ? Do i have to remove or comment out the second line in my source list ?

I don't understand what happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed comment out, or remove entirely, the second line in your `sources.list`. There is another non-obvious duplicate entry, so I would recommend changing your `sources.list` to

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib
deb http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main contrib
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main
deb https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org jessie main
deb-src https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org jessie main
```

(dropping `non-free`, and dropping `ftp.debian.org` in favour of `ftp.us.debian.org`).

You can make a backup copy and edit the file in one command:

```
sudo sed -i.bak '1,2d;s/ non-free//' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

This will make a copy of the original file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.bak`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always make a backup copy of your sources.list before you change something.

But yes, it seems like you need to comment out your duplicate lines. Try this:

`sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak`

`sudo sort -u /etc/apt/sources.list.bak > /etc/apt/sources.list`